# When the device is turned off, the last active mode is stored in the memory. -- or "stored in memory"? Which is better?

Tags: articles

From an instruction I'm translating from Russian:

> When the device is turned off, the last active mode **is stored in memory**.

Which is better - to use **the** or not to use it?

> When the device is turned off, the last active mode **is stored in the memory**.

I feel that omitting the definite article is okay, but I can't explain why.

According to Google Ngram, both options are in use:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/memory), computer memory can be countable or uncountable. Uncountable nouns do not require articles. If you are talking about computer memory in general, no article is required and it is normal not to use one, though it is not incorrect to add one.

If you follow up on actual instances in the NGram search that you quoted, you will find that many of the sentences that include the definite article go on to specify what makes it definite, for example:

> The state information associated with the user session is stored in the memory **of the web server**
>
> The fact that an expression is stored in the memory **of the system** cannot be sufficient...

In some instances, memory is the first word of a compound noun, and the final noun of the compound noun is countable and therefore does require a definite article, for example:

> The entry consists of guest page frame number , an offset value indicating where the logged memory page is stored in the memory **state log**
>
> The result is stored in the memory **location** indicated by the variable on the left - hand side.

Allowing for these, and other similar artifacts of a partially specified NGram search, the number of actual instances of **the memory** is significantly lower.